# can't get json.NET to deserialize and show my values in c#

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, json.net

Please help I can't get the values out after user json.NET

Here is the string that I get back from my jquery ajax call:

"[{\"roleInfo\":{\"roleIndex\":0,\"roleID\":\"c1_r0_23\",\"roleName\":\"Chief Executive\"}},    {\"roleInfo\":{\"roleIndex\":1,\"roleID\":\"c1_r1_192\",\"roleName\":\"Chief Operating Officer\"}}]"

Here is the webmethod that exists in my code behind on my aspx page:

List md1 = (List)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sv, typeof(List));

This is my class for MappedRole:
    public class MappedRole
    {

```
    public int roleIndex { get; set; }
    public int roleID { get; set; }
    public string roleName { get; set; }

    public MappedRole(){

    }


}
```

These are the values that I get after trying to use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject....notice that I get null and 0 values:  I try to see the values while in debug mode.

?md1[0].roleID
0
?md1[0].roleName
null
?md1[0].roleIndex
0

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run the JSON through the  JSON Validator?  I ran your sample from your question and it's not validating.  Here's the url to the validator:  http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: thank for your response! I have cleanup the string and when I use the string below I get a validated json response. [
    {
        "roleIndex": 0,
        "roleID": "c1_r0_23",
        "roleName": "ChiefExecutive"
    },
    {
        "roleIndex": 1,
        "roleID": "c1_r1_192",
        "roleName": "ComputerHardwareEngineer"
    }
]

Comment: here is how I'm getting the object to pass up into my webmethod: $(".jobRole").each(function (index) { var jobRoleIndex = index; var jobRoleID = $(this).attr('id'); var jobRoleName = $(this).text(); // add all the roleids and rolenames to the job role array. var roleInfo = { "roleIndex": jobRoleIndex, "roleID": jobRoleID, "roleName": jobRoleName };

Comment: here is my ajax call: $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CareerMap.aspx/Save_Mapped_Role",
        data: "{'savedRole': '" + JSON.stringify(mappedJobRole) + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("successfully posted data");
        },
error: function (data) {
            alert("failed posted data");
        }